# Xamarin.Forms , how from form of inputs send object to ViewModel?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Hello guys i'm making xamarin.forms app and have input form with two fields , Name and Surname , which are from object User:

**Code in xml**

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >                     
        <Entry Placeholder="Name" MaxLength="30"  Text="{Binding Name}" WidthRequest="220"> </Entry>                                                                            
        <Entry Placeholder="Surname" Text="{Binding Surname}" WidthRequest="220"></Entry>
        <Button Command={Binding SaveUserCommand }> Save user </Button>
 </StackLayout>
```

**In the ViewModel i have defined  :**

```
public Command SaveUserCommand { get; set; }  
public User user;
public User User
{
  get { return user; }
  set
  {
      if (user != value)
      {
          user = value;

          SetProperty(ref user, value);
          OnPropertyChanged("User");

      }
  }
} 
public SaveUserViewModel()
{

  SaveUserCommand = new Command(execute: async () => await ExecuteUserCommand());

}
async Task ExecuteUserCommand()
{

  try
  {

      User = await DataStore.Saveuser(User); 
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      Debug.WriteLine(ex);
  }

}
```

I want to send like object, but not working? I don't want to send like separate strings Name and Surname , i want to send them like object User? Someone can help me?

Comment: Sorry, but by using bindings you already have the `Name` and the `Surname` in the `ViewModel`, then why are you just not creating the user with those data when you reach the viewmodel ?

Comment: You can read the document to learn more about [data-binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/).

Comment: @Nikhil answered my question, i miss User.Name and User.Surname and INotify in  the object class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Model with INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation.

Something like this :-

```
public class UserModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private string _name = string.Empty;
        public string Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set => SetProperty(ref _name, value);
        }

        private string _surname = string.Empty;
        public string Surname
        {
            get => _surname;
            set => SetProperty(ref _surname, value);
        }
    }
```

And then update your xaml as below :-

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >                     
        <Entry Placeholder="Name" MaxLength="30"  Text="{Binding User.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" WidthRequest="220"> </Entry>                                                                            
        <Entry Placeholder="Surname" Text="{Binding User.Surname, Mode=TwoWay}" WidthRequest="220"></Entry>
        <Button Command={Binding SaveUserCommand }> Save user </Button>
 </StackLayout>
```

Comment: just this UserModel change User in my project because my class is User. Am i right?

Comment: one more questin. Everytime i when i binding object , i need to  SetProperty on Object in the viewModel and SetProperty of every value in the class of that object?

Comment: No you don't need to SetProperty everytime you bind the object.

Comment: and why mode= TwoWay, what that mean?